# Maven-Enforcer banDistributionManagement rule in aggregator build

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-enforcer-plugin

Given a company-pom and project structure:

```
   child (inherits from company-pom)
     +-- child2 (inherits from child)
```

When I run `mvn install` in child, with company-pom [configuration as in documentation](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banDistributionManagement.html), it fails with

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-distribution) @ child ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@234f79cb]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) fail = true
[DEBUG]   (s) failFast = false
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreCache = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce {execution: enforce-distribution}
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: com.acme.maven:child:1-SNAPSHOT @ /home/egnyte/test/child/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) ignoreParent = true
[DEBUG]   (s) rules = [org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanDistributionManagement@3020cc2d]
[DEBUG]   (s) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@4a0d851e
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Executing rule: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanDistributionManagement
[DEBUG] distributionManagement: org.apache.maven.model.DistributionManagement@393cb70a
[DEBUG] Adding failure due to exception
org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRuleException: You have defined a repository in distributionManagement.
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.utils.DistributionManagementCheck.execute(DistributionManagementCheck.java:46)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanDistributionManagement.execute(BanDistributionManagement.java:87)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceMojo.execute(EnforceMojo.java:150)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanDistributionManagement failed with message:
You have defined a repository in distributionManagement.
```

Whatever I do this rule seems to fail in a first child of a multi-module project.

Tried:

- making child a module of company-pom (and running `mvn install` from company-pom directory)
- explicitly setting `ignoreParent` to `true` and `false`

Files used to test this: ./pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.acme.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <distributionManagement>
                <repository>
                        <id>releases</id>
                        <url>https://mvnrepo.acme.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
                </repository> 
        </distributionManagement>

        <build> 
                <plugins> 
                        <plugin>
                                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>1.4</version>
                                <executions>                                     
                                        <execution>
                                                <id>enforce-distribution</id>
                                                <goals>
                                                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                                <configuration> 
                                                        <rules>
                                                                <banDistributionManagement />
                                                        </rules>
                                                </configuration>
                                        </execution>                                     
                                </executions>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>               
        </build> 

</project>
```

./child/pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
                <groupId>com.acme.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
                <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <artifactId>child</artifactId>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <modules>
        <module>child2</module>
        </modules>

</project>
```

The child 2 ./child/child2/pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
                <groupId>com.acme.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>child</artifactId> 
                <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <artifactId>child2</artifactId> 

</project>
```

Comment: From where have you called maven? From root ? Furthermore i assume you have not set one of the exceptions like `allowRepository` to true? Cause they are all set to false as default.

Comment: @khmarbaise re. "From where have you called" see edit
re. exceptions - why would I need one? Either the documentation is totally misleading or I don't want any exceptions (I want distributionManagement element only in company-pom)

Comment: Sorry if you don't like to answer question i can't help...

Comment: What? I just answered your questions, not to mention making a demo project

Comment: Hey Jakub. @khmarbaise meant that he can't help you if you don't **like** his suggestion; as opposed to, say, trying it first.

Comment: @qarma - are you channeling him or what? His comments says something different. 
Anyhow if I want to allow distributionManagement element only in company-pom what good is it to suggest I change my requirement instead of fixing the bug?

Comment: Sorry you didn't read the documentation nor have you read my comment and not answered the questions i had. Excerpt from the docs: `The above configuration will prevent any declaration of distributionManagement in your pom files except in the parent`. This references to the example in the docs which is exactly what you have copied. But you didn't try to change your configuration to see what happen. As i already mentioned you should add the `allowRepository` and set it to true.

Comment: But there are no *declaration of distributionManagement in my pom files except in the parent*. The only declaration is in the parent - so why is enforcer rule failing?